# Django: Form Model Validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an understanding issue with Form Model Validation. I have a model and additional I am adding an email_confirm field in my form. However, the validation doesn't work. Anyone who can help me to understand why?

```
class TransactionProfileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email_confirm = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model=TransactionProfile
        fields = [
            'email',
            'email_confirm',
            'address_line_1',
            'address_line_2',
            'city',
            'country',
            'postal_code',
            'state'
        ]

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_confirm = self.cleaned_data.get('email_confirm')
        if email and email_confirm and email != email_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Emails don't match.")
        return email
```

However, if I am trying this code here it works:

```
    def clean_email_confirm(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_confirm = self.cleaned_data.get('email_confirm')
        if email and email_confirm and email != email_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Emails don't match.")
        return email_confirm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cleaned_data['email_confirm']` doesn't exist at the point `clean_email()` is called, because the confirm field field has not yet been cleaned.

Fields are cleaned in alphabetical order, so doing the comparison in `clean_email_confirm()` works. However this is an implementation detail and should not be relied on; as the docs state, any validation that relies on two or more fields should be done in the generic `clean()` method rather than any of the field-specific methods.

Comment: Ahh perfect. Now it's working. I didn't know that, thank you. I am just struggling with one last detail in the documentation. When should I use cleaned_data = super().clean() and when only super().clean()

I tried to understand it, but it wasn't clear to me - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: All that is a bit irrelevant; you're not subclassing an existing form with its own clean method, so you should just access `self.cleaned_data` directly.

Comment: Okay, I will do this then. Thank you Daniel!